# How to fix broken images and icons in jenkins UI

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am having trouble with the jenkins ui these days with all the images and icons (build icons and those in the manage jenkins page) broken. I have googled and haven't found anything clear. Also, the jenkins became much slower. I read that clearing the TEMP folder might cause this issue. and yes after restarting the jenkins service on the instance it has become much worse and all icons were broken. How can I fix it? Screenshots attached Can someone help me with this.
location of `jenkins.war : /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`

jenkins version: 1.651.2
instance : ubuntu
size: t2.large
I have these files in the tmp dir:

```
hs_err_pid9138.log,  jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-war--any- , winstone3877623187585170658.jar, 
winstone6494081310724055556.jar, hsperfdata_jenkins,
jna--1712433994 ,winstone5277385331684199945.jar
```

[image: broken icons - jenkins]

[image: broken icons -jenkins]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some research found this and it helped:

do:

```
 - sudo service jenkins stop
 - sudo mv /var/cache/jenkins/war /var/cache/jenkins/war.gone
 - sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Doesn't help :-(

Comment: Didn't help! :(